# Laptop not booting after fresh ubuntu mate 15 install

Tags: grub2, uefi, mate

I just installed Ubuntu Mate 15 onto my laptop. After a successful install, I can't seem to boot into the OS. There's a blinking cursor on the screen and that's it. I used a LiveCD to try repairing it using boot repair but that also didn't help. Also tried disabling SecureBoot in BIOS: There wasn't any option like that in my BIOS.

The boot repair report is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15585301/.

I'm new to Linux so I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've clearly got an EFI-mode installation. That's fine, and helps identify the problem, which I believe is this:

```
=================== efibootmgr -v
Timeout: 10 seconds
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
```

Ordinarily, the EFI `BootOrder` variable tells the firmware what OS to boot. It's not set on your computer, though, so it can't tell what to boot. What brand and model computer do you have? I've got an older HP laptop (a ProBook 6470b) that's got a broken firmware that can't accept this variable. The solution is to copy the boot loader file to the fallback filename of `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`.

One complication is that you've already got a file of this name; however, because the name is fixed and Boot Repair doesn't try to identify programs' contents, it's not clear what this file is in your case. Whatever it is, though, it's not doing anything useful. Thus, I recommend you replace it as follows:

1. Boot to an emergency system (whatever you used to run Boot Repair will probably work).
2. Open a Terminal window.
3. Mount the ESP (`/dev/sda1`) someplace convenient. For instance, `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` will mount it at `/mnt`.
4. Change to the `EFI` directory on the ESP (`cd /mnt/EFI`).
5. Rename the current `Boot` directory, as in `mv Boot Boot-old`. (Note that the ESP uses FAT, which is case-insensitive.)
6. Copy the entire `ubuntu` subdirectory to `BOOT`, as in `sudo cp -r ubuntu BOOT`.
7. Rename `shimx64.efi` in `BOOT` to `bootx64.efi`, as in `sudo mv BOOT/shimx64.efi BOOT/bootx64.efi`.
8. Verify that what should be present is by typing `ls /mnt/EFI/BOOT`. You should see several files, including `bootx64.efi` and `grubx64.efi`.
9. Reboot. With any luck, the computer will boot normally.

As a side note, this sort of problem was common in early EFI implementations (from 2012 and earlier). This problem *should not exist* in more recent computers. If the computer is new, I ***STRONGLY*** recommend you return it to the store for a refund and get something else, since any computer with such an egregious problem is badly broken, and you don't know what else might be equally badly broken. Even if everything else is fine, maintaining a boot loader like this will be an ongoing hassle for the rest of the life of the computer.

Comment: I'm using a Samsung RV511

Comment: I found a review of that model from 2011, so it seems old enough to plausibly have a flaky early UEFI, similar in this respect to my HP.

Comment: Tried doing what you said. Didn't work. Appreciate it though

Comment: If you're not trying to dual-boot alongside another OS, you could try activating the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; aka "legacy boot support" or a similar term) in the firmware and install in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. That will install a BIOS-mode boot loader, which works better with some older systems. You'll need to be sure to boot the installer in BIOS mode, though, and controlling that can be tricky. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more on this subject.